# Problems with Windows Aero Theme

Tags: interface

So I have this strange bug where the Windows' Aero Desktop Theme gets switched on and off everytime I open and close Blender. It's not that much of a deal, except that some animations I'm used to get somehow laggy and the overall color is much brighter (I pick dark colors/transparency on Aero for eye health).

I never really had this kind of problem before, but this has been happening since I formatted my pc and reinstalled Windows 7 and Blender again.

All drivers and software versions are up to date. I'm using a GTX 750 ti with Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit and Blender 2.77a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a Nvidia Driver issue (I was using v.372.54) even though their online support denied so.

Downgraded to v.368.81 and everything is back to normal :D